# How do I resize this image using tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, resize, urllib

I want to use urllib and Tkinter to resize an image. However, I do not know how to resize the image. This is not my code, but I would like to see how it would be done using this code.

```
from io import BytesIO
import urllib
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
url = "https://www.thoughtco.com/thmb/O8fvqeXnAtOZ_L4eQ-aCRFKou_I=/768x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/atlantic-bottlenose-dolphin--jumping-high-during-a-dolphin-training-demonstration-154724035-59ce93949abed50011352530.jpg"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
    raw_data = u.read()
img = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
iimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label = tk.Label(image=iimage)

label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I try to resize it:

```
iimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize(50,50, Image.ANTIALIAS))
```

It gives me this error:

`ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (50). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)`

Comment: The size is a tuple. https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass size as a `tuple`. So it would look like this:

`iimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((50,50), Image.ANTIALIAS))`

Answer (score 1):

I Suggest you use PhotoImage and SubSample like:

```
Example = PhotoImage(file='photo.png')
```

then subsampling like:

```
Example = Example.subsample(2, 2)
```

total Code:

```
Example = PhotoImage(file='Photo.png')
Example = Example.subsample(3, 3)
```

In Summery:
**You Wont Be Needed To Import Any Special Type of Libarys And Can Be Used On Any python3 IDE's**